# How to print UTC or GMT using SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to print a date in this format:

```
2023-01-11 09:25:52 UTC
```

But when I use date format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z
```

I get:

```
2023-01-11 09:29:25 +0100
```

While searching by existing question in stack overflow, I found similar questions but not with this exact format with "UTC" at the end. I found one that provided a solution to add the format as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'` but then it would force the a GMT value to wrongly show UTC at the end.

Most of the answers explain how to get UTC value, but not how to print in this format

```
2023-01-11 09:25:52 UTC
```

Some solutions were also suggesting to use something else than SimpleDateFormat.

This question was marked as duplicated, but none of the post that were supposed to be duplicated had the info that I wanted.

Comment: Switch from the error-prone legacy date-time API to the modern date-time API. [Here](https://ideone.com/gSvgsH) is a solution using the modern API.

Comment: By *a date* did you mean a `java.util.Date`? I strongly recommend you neither use that class, it’s poorly designed and nothing you should struggle with, nor the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). For example `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ROOT))` (just gave `2023-01-11 14:23:11 UTC`).

Comment: Did you remember to search before asking? What did or did you not find? Very similar questions have been asked and answered a lot of times before.

Comment: If you are getting a `Date` from a legacy API that you cannot upgrade, use `yourOldfashionedUtilDate .toInstant() .atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ROOT))`. Example result is `2023-01-11 09:25:52 UTC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lowercase `z` instead of `Z` to get the offset instead of the id. And you have to set the time zone using `simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`.

Example:

```java
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date)); // 2023-01-11 08:41:17 UTC
```

Comment: I tried this same thing but with an Upper case Z and it didn't work. 

I tried with lower case z as in you example and it worked percet. Thanks.

Comment: While your code gives the desired output, neither the OP nor you nor anyone else should use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are troublesome and long outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance of simpleDateFormat with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` date format is incorrect change to capital `Z` to small `z`,

then it works as expected.

`2023-01-11 09:25:52 UTC`